# Feedhenry MBaaS integration

Tags: ios, openshift, redhat, rhmap, feedhenry

I am going to play with Red Hat FeedHenry MBaaS services. I have some basic doubts about it. I didn't purchase this yet. However to get any technical support prior, I don't have any online developer support with them. Seeking help from this forum.

Does Feedhenry MBaaS support for my Native iOS & Android projects? I read about, cloud based App support from Feedhenry MBaaS, but not sure it can support for Native projects too? I mean, I have my existing native iOS project developed. Can I use the same existing project and just utilize only Red Hat MBaaS service? If this is possible, what are the steps to follow?
Basically the questions is, Can I get MBaaS service alone from Red Hat (or) I need to purchase the entire Red Hat Mobile Platform suite? But I want to utilize only their MBaaS.

Appreciate your responses. Please help with your answers.

Answer (score 0):

FeedHenry is now known as RHMAP (Red Hat Mobile Application Platform). We've been using it to mobile front end other systems at a few of our client sites.

> Does Feedhenry MBaaS support for my Native iOS & Android projects?

The platform is more geared towards hybrid (Cordova) apps, and that is all I have used it for. However, it does have capability for native projects as well. I can't speak to how well native projects import, but I have imported an existing Ionic project before, and that works perfectly fine now, with a tiny bit of elbow grease. The code is hosted on their own git repo, so importing should be as easy as pushing your code up there.

> Basically the questions is, Can I get MBaaS service alone from Red Hat (or) I need to purchase the entire Red Hat Mobile Platform suite?

You need to buy the whole suite, but can hit the server apps individually though. But I would think if you were just using the platform to host your node apps, you could host them yourself for much cheaper. The advantage of a platform like RHMAP is that you have everything managed for you under the one roof.

With that said, the long answer:

Typically, a RHMAP project is structured as:

Client App <-> Cloud App <-> MBaaS (sometimes multiple)

Your Cloud App should contain the business logic required for your server side, while the MBaaS typically acts as a wrapper around an external system, providing RESTFul endpoints for your Cloud App to access. You can find a list of supported setups [here](https://access.redhat.com/node/2357761).

RHMAP provide an API, and some base code to set up Cloud and MBaaS apps. You can choose to make these public (and have API keys setup), meaning you can utilise these node apps individually outside the platform.

I'd recommend importing your client apps, if you do decide to go with RHMAP, and utilising the platform as a whole. But as I have said earlier. If you wanted to use the platform only to host your server code, you're probably better off finding cheaper options elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to supplement here that you can check all which is supported or not into RHMAP in "Red Hat Mobile Application Platform Supported Configurations"[1] page.

About your questions:

- Does Feedhenry MBaaS support for my Native iOS & Android projects?

  Yes, you can.
- Can I use the same existing project and just utilize only Red Hat MBaaS service?

  You can import your projects for RHMAP and do the required configuration as you can find the documentation "CHAPTER 5. IMPORTING CLIENT APPS AND CLOUD APPS INTO PROJECTS"[2]
- If this is possible, what are the steps to follow?

  This process is documented step by step into the doc "CHAPTER 5. IMPORTING CLIENT APPS AND CLOUD APPS INTO PROJECTS"[2]

[1] - https://access.redhat.com/node/2357761

[2] - https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_mobile_application_platform/4.1/html/server-side_developer_guide/importing-client-apps-and-cloud-apps-into-projects